# Running the page that needs time for the result with cronjob

Tags: php, cron

I have a php page (the code below) and with this page I get information from 70 sites and send a mail. This information is about the version of the site and the size of its files.

When I call my control page manually in the browser, the process is completed in about a minute and an email is sent to all sites.

However, when I call with a cronjob, the mail comes up, but probably because it doesn't get the information, it doesn't.

Probably the cronjob does not work like manual calling.
What can I do?

```
    $yp_PathRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
session_start();

$yp_PathSettings = '/panel/functions/settings.php';
include_once($yp_PathRoot . $yp_PathSettings);

function zCheck($myWebSite){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://$myWebSite/panel/?qc=1");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    $output2 = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $output2;
}

$array = array(
    "domain1.ext",
    "domain2.ext",
    ...
    "domain68.ext",
    "domain69.ext",
    "domain70.ext"
);

$myMessage = "";
foreach($array as $value)
{
    $checkedSite    = $value;
    $checkedValues  = zCheck($value);
    $exlodedValues  = explode('|', $checkedValues);

    $myCase                     = $exlodedValues[0];
    $klySoftwareSizeSF          = $exlodedValues[1];
    $errorAcceptableSize        = $exlodedValues[2];
    $showQuotaYakinSF           = $exlodedValues[3];
    $klyThemeAndImagesSizeSF    = $exlodedValues[4];
    $showQuotaHesapliSF         = $exlodedValues[5];
    $fromMailer                 = $exlodedValues[6];
    $myUserName                 = $exlodedValues[7];

    switch($myCase) {
        case 1:
            $statusMessage  = "There is an increase in the size of non-theme files. Check the error files. If there is no error file, look for another file with a larger size.";
            $quotaClass     = " style=\"color:black;\"";
            $softwareClass  = " style=\"color:red;\"";
            break;
        case 2:
            $statusMessage = "User uploaded images and files are about to fill the quota.";
            $quotaClass     = " style=\"color:orange;\"";
            $softwareClass  = " style=\"color:black;\"";
            break;
        case 3:
            $statusMessage = "The size of the images and files uploaded by the user has filled the quota.";
            $quotaClass     = " style=\"color:red;\"";
            $softwareClass  = " style=\"color:black;\"";
            break;
        case 4:
            $statusMessage = "Everything is OK.";
            $quotaClass     = " style=\"color:black;\"";
            $softwareClass  = " style=\"color:black;\"";
            break;
    }
    $myMessage =  $myMessage."<br/><b>".$checkedSite."</b><br/>Site checked. ".$statusMessage."<br/><table><tr $softwareClass><td>Software Size<td><td>: $klySoftwareSizeSF<td></tr><tr $quotaClass><td>Size of Themes and Images<td><td>: $klyThemeAndImagesSizeSF<td></tr><tr $quotaClass><td>Site Quota<td><td>: $showQuotaHesapliSF<td></tr></table>";
}

$fromMailer         = "\"Postman\" <from@domain.ext>";
$myUserName         = "Postman";
$mailFuncFrom       = "$fromMailer";
$mailFuncTo         = "\"Postman\" <to@domain.ext>";
$mailFuncSubject    = "Daily Quota Check";
$clientServerName   = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$clientRequestUrl   = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$clientUserName     = $myUserName;
$mailFuncContent    = "<b>Site:</b> $clientServerName<br/><b>> The page on which the message was sent:</b> $clientRequestUrl<br/><b>User:</b> $clientUserName<br/><br/>Hello,<br/>Daily check completed. The status of the sites is as follows.<br/><br/>$myMessage";
$mailSendMethod     = 1;

sendMyMail($mailFuncFrom,$mailFuncTo,$mailFuncSubject,$mailFuncContent,$mailSendMethod);
```

Comment: You should start by debugging the issue to see what's actually going on and where it fails. Then, if you aren't able to solve it your self, you should post all relevant code and what debugging/conclusions you've come to. Without seeing the code, it's impossible for us to give you more help.

Comment: Please see my answer, you are using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` on your cron, both web-specific server variables not available on the CLI version of PHP.

Comment: It started to work, whereas I did not make any changes. Before I sent this message, I compared the code I added here with my own code and it's the same. 
Actually, I made the change, I saw your message, but it didn't matter to remove it either. Thank you. @JoshWood thank you.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson , A solution could not be found here because the code that was not working already worked. Do you think this title should be deleted? Or should it remain an example code?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you are using php features intended for the web in a cron script, which is run with php-cli.

Many web-specific features such as sessions (`$_SESSION` and its related functions), cookies, some web-specific `$_SERVER` variables such as `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and more are not available in cron jobs.

You should either setup a new cron to make a web request to your current cron (if that makes sense), or modify the cron to not use web-specific php features.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that hasn't got close to enough info in them. We have _no idea_ what the OP are or aren't using or what actually happens so any answer would just be wild guesses.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Actually this is enough info for me, as I had a very similar issue and I can almost guarantee this is the reasoning if it is working on web and not cli. The fact that the script works in browser and not command line is enough information for me to help diagnose.

Comment: It could still be many different reasons for the issue since we don't know where it actually goes wrong. It's better to teach people to ask proper questions than assuming and guessing.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson My 'guess and assumption' was correct though, look at his code on his edit.. It really wasn't a guess dude I have had the issue many times

Comment: If your assumption/guess was correct or not doesn't actually change my point. The answer was still a bit premature since the OP's question wasn't complete. If people write answers using assumptions and guesses, it's very likely that questions will have a lot of irrelevant/wrong answers, which just muddies the waters for the OP and for future visitors. The questions/answers might also be harder to search for if there aren't enough info in the question. We all need to help out and try to avoid those kind of situations.

Comment: And yes, it was actually a guess. It was an _educated_ guess, but still a guess.